# Is it possible to send a Google hangouts chat message using node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-hangouts

I'm looking for a way to send a message to the new Gmail chat window - Google Hangout apparently. I'm aware XMPP is supported for old-style chats, but is there an API to send anything using Google Hangouts from node.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/jaxbot/hangouts-bot

Install

```
npm install hangouts-bot
```

Code

```
var hangoutsBot = require("hangouts-bot");
var bot = new hangoutsBot("someone@gmail.com", "password");

bot.on('online', function() {
    console.log('online');
});

bot.on('message', function(from, message) {
    console.log(from + ">> " + message);
});
```

Original source: [hangouts-bot README](https://github.com/jaxbot/hangouts-bot/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: An FYI to any new people finding this answer from google, 
As of at least 2018 google has turn off  XMPP integrations.
 https://github.com/jaxbot/hangouts-bot/issues/14